# Ubuntu 20.04 Freeze for AMD

Tags: 20.04, freeze

Just installed ubuntu 20.04 and got frequently freeze after sometime.
Can someone help me?

```
free -h:

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7,5Gi       1,7Gi       4,2Gi       228Mi       1,6Gi       5,4Gi
Swap:          15Gi          0B        15Gi

❯ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60

❯ sudo lshw -C memory
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 2.70
       date: 03/16/2018
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: f
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0,4 ns)
          product: V-GeN D4S4GL26A16TS6
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000032
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0,4 ns)
          product: V-GeN D4S4GL26A16TS6
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000032
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 11
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 12
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 2MiB
       capacity: 2MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 13
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3

❯ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
2.7
```

0